# Get value via Reflection from double nested class

Tags: c#, reflection

currently I'm trying to get the value of a property from a nested class. Unfortunately I'm getting a parameter as `object`. I know the interal structure, but I couldn't puzzle out, how to reach through to the property.

For easy testing I prepared some lines of code:

```
namespace ns{
    public class OuterClass{
        public InnerClass ic = new InnerClass();
    }
    public class InnerClass {
        private string test="hello";
        public string Test { get { return test; } }
    }
}
```

Calling this directly is easy:

```
var oc = new ns.OuterClass();
string test = oc.ic.Test;
```

But when I try to get the value via reflection, I run into `System.Reflection.TargetException`:

```
object o = new ns.OuterClass();
var ic_field=o.GetType().GetField("ic");
var test_prop = ic_field.FieldType.GetProperty("Test");
string test2 = test_prop.GetValue(???).ToString();
```

What do I have to use as the object within `GetValue()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the value of `ic` from the `FieldInfo`:

```
object ic = ic_field.GetValue(o);
```

Then you pass that to `test_prop.GetValue`:

```
string test2 = (string)test_prop.GetValue(ic, null);
```

Comment: Yep, to elaborate, when you use `GetProperty("SomeName")` you get just metadata about the structure of the property(`PropertyInfo`), not the actual property value itself nor the object it references.  The `PropertyInfo` knows nothing about an instance of the class, thus `GetValue` requires you give it an actual reference to the object that you want to perform the property access on.

Comment: Thank you! I just found it myself. I placed `ic_field.GetValue(o)` in the place of the three `???` and it worked. Great answer. +1 and accept it.